# Searching for powerfull AI modules to improve teef gloves

Tags: real-time

I have seen the teef glove ofNavid Azodi and Thomas Pryor, like this :

[image]
and also seen [this post](https://amp.theatlantic.com/amp/article/545441/) which has been said about this kind of work problem :

> Their six-page letter, which Padden passed along to the dean, points
>   out how the SignAloud gloves—and all the sign-language translation
>   gloves invented so far—misconstrue the nature of ASL (and other sign
>   languages) by focusing on what the hands do. Key parts of the grammar
>   of ASL include “raised or lowered eyebrows, a shift in the orientation
>   of the signer’s torso, or a movement of the mouth,” reads the letter.
>   “Even perfectly functioning gloves would not have access to facial
>   expressions.” ASL consists of thousands of signs presented in
>    sophisticated ways that have, so far, confounded reliable machine
>   recognition. One challenge for machines is the complexity of ASL and
>   other sign languages. Signs don’t appear like clearly delineated beads
>   on a string; they bleed into one another in a process that linguists
>   call “coarticulation” (where, for instance, a hand shape in one sign
>   anticipates the shape or location of the following sign; this happens
>   in words in spoken languages, too, where sounds can take on
>   characteristics of adjacent ones). Another problem is the lack of
>   large data sets of people signing that can be used to train
>   machine-learning algorithms.

So i like to know what proper AI module do you know for doing the navid works better by adding for first step the geometrical position analyzing into it, i like to use popular AI blocks like [Tensorfliw](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) for doing this kind of analyzing by fast online and the modules which updated at the time by large community users.

Update:

I think, some Virtual reality analyzer for the position analyzing must be existing, so which one if popular and free to contributing with large community?

thanks for your attention.